# See history renames in specific ftp file

Tags: linux, ftp

Well, some FTP files in my server are renamed and now i need back to original file name. There is anyway to see the original file name ?

```
I.E: 

1) In 2017/01/01 the file was created with name "ABC.mp4"
2) In 2017/01/05 the file was renamed to "XYC.mp4"
3) In 2017/02/04 the file was renamed to "BOA.xta"
```

There is anyway to trace this renames?

This is my syslog.conf:

```
#       Spaces ARE valid field separators in this file. However,
#       other *nix-like systems still insist on using tabs as field
#       separators. If you are sharing this file between systems, you
#       may want to use only tabs as field separators here.
#       Consult the syslog.conf(5) manpage.
*.err;kern.warning;auth.notice;mail.crit                /dev/console
*.notice;authpriv.none;kern.debug;lpr.info;mail.crit;news.err   /var/log/messages
security.*                                      /var/log/security
auth.info;authpriv.info                         /var/log/auth.log
mail.info                                       /var/log/maillog
lpr.info                                        /var/log/lpd-errs
ftp.*                                           /var/log/xferlog
cron.*                                          /var/log/cron
*.=debug                                        /var/log/debug.log
*.emerg                                         *
# uncomment this to log all writes to /dev/console to /var/log/console.log
#console.info                                   /var/log/console.log
# uncomment this to enable logging of all log messages to /var/log/all.log
# touch /var/log/all.log and chmod it to mode 600 before it will work
#*.*                                            /var/log/all.log
# uncomment this to enable logging to a remote loghost named loghost
#*.*                                            @loghost
# uncomment these if you're running inn
# news.crit                                     /var/log/news/news.crit
# news.err                                      /var/log/news/news.err
# news.notice                                   /var/log/news/news.notice
!ppp
*.*                                             /var/log/ppp.log
```

Comment: This may be in the log files, it depends on what FTP server your are running.

Comment: i'm using proftpd

Comment: By default it logs to `/etc/syslog.conf` there will be alot of other stuff in there, have a look. See if you can do a grep on it.

Comment: i edited my post with content of syslog.conf

Comment: Have a look at `/var/log/xferlog`?

Comment: I looked at this file but i didnt found any rename command